# Как принять число от пользователя боту и записать это число в переменную для дальнейшего использования в формуле? ТГ бот, aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

По способам из интернета переменную у меня получилось сохранить, но она не сбрасывалась при повторном включении бота, поэтому и это мне нужно исключить.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Нужно использовать какие-либо постоянные хранилища. Самое простое - сохранить в файл, либо подключить базы данных SQL или проще - redis.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: для этого действия в aiogram есть FSM (Finite State Machine)